# apex retrieve default item value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Is it possible to get default item value using plsql? I have a validation and in case it fails I want to reset item to its default value.
I tried using `apex_util.set_session_state('P_ITEM_NAME', null)` but that did not have any noticeable effect.

How can default item be retrieved or item itself be reset?

Answer (score 2):

When creating a page process, there is a condition called "Inline validation errors displayed", maybe this will help? In this process you can reset items to null, then when page loads, item values will return to their default values.

UPD:

Create process:

- Process Point: On Load Before header
- Condition: Inline Validation Errors Displayed
- Process source:

  ```
  begin
    for i in (
     select t.ITEM_DEFAULT, t.item_name
      from apex_application_page_items t
      where t.application_id = :APP_ID
        and t.page_id = :APP_PAGE_ID
    ) loop
      apex_util.set_session_state(i.item_name, i.item_default);
    end loop;
  end;
  ```

This will return all page items to their default values.
This solution some ugly, but i don't know another solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`:P_ITEM_NAME := null;`

The difference here is the ":" infront of the item. Using it like this will give access to the item. Using apostrophes isn't needed I believe.

If this doesn't work with your version try without the ;.

So you can use:

```
:P_ITEM_NAME
```

To get the value.

Comment: Apostrophes are necessary as `set_session_state` accepts `varchar2` name of item. Calling `set_session_state` from validator function is not useful as it seems that session state and item value are the same thing and if I clean session state item value is also cleared. I there were something like request scope. I found a solution however rather ugly one.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any function that would return me default value using an item. However I could use default item setting to mimic this. Page processes do not run when page has validation errors, so I added conditional page process that performs the same checks as my validation and when these checks indicate that validation fails it just clears item state.

This is ugly as it requires checks to be duplicated and it seems that it is necessary to replicate almost same page controls through all pages where such reset mechanism is necessary.